# External HD file recovery & folder structure software

Tags: windows, linux, data-recovery, filesystems

I was entrusted with a corrupted external 2.5" HD to try to recover its contents. Ideally, it should recover both the files and the disk folder structure. First, I've tried it with Testdisk and Photorec (Windows version). It recovered some files, but mainly the recycle bin ones, so only a small slight of the desired content. Also, it doesn't preserved the folder structure/file names. Also tried Recuva (Windows), but it doesn't even recognize the drive, so I can't use it. I'm now trying Glarysoft File Recovery Free, to see what happens.

The 1$ million question is: what other promising options do I have? As mentioned, ideally it should be able to recover both the files & file structure. Of course that I prefer free/opensource software, but I can also consider to buy something that proves being worthwhile. I can use Windows or Linux.

Comment: While i don't know which other software I could recommend, a reminder of caution: unless you didn't already do so, the very first thing you should do is to make an image from the corrupted disk – and then only run recovery software against (a copy of) that image. Each time you try the disk directly decreases your chances for future success, as it could corrupt things even more. If you corrupt the image copy, you can copy the original image again and start over as often as needed. // That said, not sure if it still lives, but there also was Foremost.

Comment: File scavengers in general cannot preserve folder or even file names if the directory structure is destroyed. They have to literally look at every block on the disk & try to figure out if it belongs to any other related block. If chkdisk has been run before the scavenger, the chances of name recovery are lowered.